# angularjs: nested ng-repeat is repeated more times of the length of the outer array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I don't know why a ng-repeat is repeated more times of the length of the outer array. This is the array:

```
$scope.giornieventi = [{
    Intestazione: "Questa settimana",
    Eventi: [{
            Nome: "Giacomo",
            Immagine: "",
            Url: "://www.....",
            Data: "Oggi"
        },
        {
            Nome: "Giacomo2",
            Immagine: "",
            Url: "Ciao",
            Data: "Domani"
        }]
},
{
    Intestazione: "Settimana successiva",
    Eventi: [{
            Nome: "Roberto",
            Immagine: "",
            Url: "Ciao",
            Data: "Oggi"
        },
        {
            Nome: "Roberto2",
            Immagine: "",
            Url: "Ciao",
            Data: "Domani"
        }]
}];
```

This is the ng-repeat it does not work properly:

```
<div ng-repeat="giorno in giornieventi">
    <h3 ng-show="alertData(giorno.Intestazione)">@{{ giorno.Intestazione }}</h3>
    <article ng-repeat="evento in giorno.Eventi">
        @{{ evento.Nome }}
    </article>
</div>
```

This is the control function:

```
$scope.alertData= function(Intestazione) {
    alert(Intestazione); return true;
}
```

The strange behaviour is that I get the alert 4 times instead of 2 and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine except using the `ng-show` to get an alert.
`ng-show` evaluates each time something in the scope has changed to determine if the element should be shown, so you are seeing everything happening twice (making it 4 alerts instead of 2) because AngularJS evaluates the `ng-show` twice.

Try changing it to `ng-init` which runs once when the element is loaded:

```
<div ng-repeat="giorno in giornieventi">
    <h3 ng-init="alertData(giorno.Intestazione)">@{{ giorno.Intestazione }}</h3>
    <article ng-repeat="evento in giorno.Eventi">
        @{{ evento.Nome }}
    </article>
</div>
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6618/

Comment: Great it worked. But I used ng-show somewhere else and it was giving only 2 alerts ?

Comment: You should use `ngShow` when you want to decide if to show or hide an element, you don't control when it runs, Angular does. As you can see the `<article>` element is created twice as expected. You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Ok.That means it was executing 4 times due to dirty check.

Comment: If you had a more complex template where things kept changing and re-evaluating it would continue executing more times. The thing to remember is that you don't control it. `ngInit` you can better control since it happens only when the element is loaded to the template. But some people consider it bad practice to even use `ngInit`.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks alot. Why they consider it a bad practice ?